# JS добавление класса в цикле

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Есть такая проблема. На странице расположено несколько элементов .paralax при прокрутке им должен добавляться класс fixed при достижении определенного места. Делается это при скроле с помощью следующего js-кода:

```
    var browserWindowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var paralax = document.getElementsByClassName( 'paralax' );

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function ( event ) {

  for ( let i = 0; i < paralax.length; i++ ) {
    const paralaxItem = paralax[i];
    var distanceToBottom = paralaxItem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if ( distanceToBottom <= browserWindowHeight ) {
      paralaxItem.classList.add( 'fixed' );
    }
    else {
      paralaxItem.classList.remove( 'fixed' );
    }
  }
```

} )

Соответственно данный класс должен удалятся при прокрутке страницы назад.
Проблема заключается в том, что класс добавляется, но когда страница прокручивается далее и класс должен по идее оставаться присвоенным, он почему-то (для меня-новичка) мигает, т. е. при скролле я вижу в панели, что присвоенный класс то добавляется, то удаляется очень быстро. Если убрать блок else, то все идет нормально, класс не мигает, но он не убирается при скролле элемента назад.

Comment: Попробуй добавить проверку на наличие класса fixed, перед тем как добавить его: if (![...paralaxItem.classList].includes('fixed')) paralaxItem.classList.add( 'fixed' );

Comment: Хотелось бы выидеть рабочий прмиер кода, в котором наблюдается данное поведение.